# How do I increment a counter inside a while test of Python

Tags: python, while-loop, increment

How would you translate the following Java idiom to Python?

```
Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi;
int i = lo, j = hi+1;
Comparable v = a[lo];

while (a[++i] < v) if (i == hi) break;
```

My problem is that in the while test I cannot have a `++i` or `i += 1`.

Comment: And the intended outcome? `i` being the highest index between `lo` and `hi` that is lower than `i[lo]`?

Answer (score 10):

The problem you can't do that way in Python is a restriction of Python syntax. Let's get what does `while` look like from documentation:

```
while_stmt ::=  "while" expression ":" suite
                ["else" ":" suite]
```

As You can see you must put **expression** before "**:**", while `x += 1` is a statement (*and statements doesn't return any value so cannot be used as a condition*).

Here's what does this code look like in Python:

```
i += 1
while a[i] < v:
    if i == hi:
        break
    i += 1
```

Though it works, it's most likely not a Python way to solve your problem. When you have a collection and you want to use indices you have to look forward to redesigning your code using `for` loop and [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function.

**P.S.**

Anyway, direct code porting between languages with absolutely different philosophies is not a good way to go.

Comment: BTW - I wouldn't call this a *syntax limitation*.  It is a philosophical restriction that the language imposes.

Comment: My code needs to check that "a[++i] < v" 
namely, i needs to be incremented prior to the test. The solution you present, does not do that (it checks a[i]).

Comment: @D.Shawley, will agree with you here. The word "limitation" was born in my mind due to long-term communication with Ruby-guys and in Ruby everything is an expression).

Comment: @user1656850: the code in the answer as it stands now increments `i`, then does the test. It's functionally the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, two problems: 

A for loop is good if the number of iteration is known in advance, so it may apply in my example, but not in all cases (whereas a while loop can be applied in all cases).

The solution you give will not increment the i on the last test (as the loop body will not be entered into), whereas the Java code will increment the i on the last check (because the ++i is done prior to the check).

Comment: @user1656850: your analysis of the example is wrong.  The Python while loop here will produce the same results as your Java code.

Comment: Ned, in the Java case, when a[X] >= V, the i will be one greater than in the Python case.

Comment: @user1656850: In the java case, the i is pre-incremented, so if the test fails, it will be because a[i] >= v.  The same is true of the Python code.  When the loop ends due to finding an element >= v, the value of i after the loop will be the index of the offending element.

Answer (score 4):

The Java code sets i to the index of either the first element >= a[lo], or to hi, whichever appears first.  So:

```
v = a[lo]
for i in range(lo+1, hi+1):
    if a[i] >= v:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over all the objects in a list or any "iterable" thing, use "for item in list". If you need a counter as well, use enumerate. If you want a range of numbers use range or xrange.

But sometimes you really do want a loop with a counter that just goes up which you're going to break out of with break or return, just like in the original poster's example.

For these occasions I define a simple generator just to make sure I can't forget to increment the counter.

```
def forever(start=0):
    count = start
    while True:
        yield count
        count += 1
```

Then you can just write things like:

```
for count in forever():
    if do_something() == some_value:
        break
return count
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list` class has a built-in method that does this kind of searching, but for whatever reason it only compares for equality. Of course, we can hack that:

```
class hax:
  def __init__(self, value): self.value = value
  def __eq__(self, other): return other >= self.value

a.index(hax(a[lo]), lo + 1, hi + 1)
```

... but please don't :)

Anyway, not only should you not be trying to port the code directly, as @Rostyslav suggests - you shouldn't really be trying to port the *problem* directly. There's something very strange about a Python program that uses lists in a way that would allow a problem like this to come up.